# ansible insert rows into mysql db

Tags: mysql, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am novice to ansible and trying out few use cases to grab more knowledge. I am trying out one use case where I plan to connect to MYSQL db and run one select query. What I am trying is shown in the playbook below. This code works fine. Now I want to run one insert query to insert some rows from .csv file. How can I achieve this?

ansible playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  #become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Excute query to db  with positional arguments
      community.mysql.mysql_query:
        login_host: sqltest-lb-fm-in.dbaas.domain.com
        login_user: devops_baseline_db
        login_password: *********
        login_port: 3307
        login_db: mydb
        ca_cert : mydomain-SHA256-Root-CA.crt
        query: SELECT * FROM Inventory
      register: output
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ output }}"
```

example of `/tmp/report.csv` content

```
Date,Hostname/IP,OS-Version,Package-Name,Pre-installed-Package-Status,Current-Installed-Version,Post-installed-Package-Status,log-loc
2022-12-15,10.109.20.12,12.5,curl,up-to-date,7.60.0-11.49.1,up-to-date,http://hostname/log_dir/
2022-12-15,10.109.20.12,12.5,libcurl4-32bit,up-to-date,7.60.0-11.49.1,up-to-date,http://hostname/log_dir/
2022-12-15,10.109.20.12,12.5,libcurl4,up-to-date,7.60.0-11.49.1,up-to-date,http://hostname/log_dir/
2022-12-15,10.109.20.12,12.5,libtiff5,up-to-date,4.0.9-44.56.1,up-to-date,http://hostname/log_dir/
```

Comment: Please see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/read_csv_module.html

Comment: Thanks. I didnt find the code which would read rows from csv file and insert that into my sql db. Could you please share that logic with me.

Comment: Sure: Read the csv with the above linked module, [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html) on the result in your `mysql_query` task to send the queries that will insert your csv data to mysql as you expect. Now if you still have problems while implementing this, [edit] your question with a [mre] of the code you will write when attempting to fulfill your requirement and explain what is your exact problem, the result you get and the one you expect instead. You might also want to read [ask]. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have Three ways**

**1. using ansible mysqldb module (Not working but expected to work) :**

```yaml
- name: Copy database dump file
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: /tmp/report.csv
    dest: /tmp

- name: Restore database
  community.mysql.mysql_db:
    name: my_db
    state: import
    target: /tmp/report.csv
```

**2. Using Commands:**

```yaml
- name: Copy database dump file
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: /tmp/report.csv
    dest: /tmp

- name: Excute query to db  with positional arguments
  community.mysql.mysql_query:
    login_host: sqltest-lb-fm-in.dbaas.domain.com
    login_user: devops_baseline_db
    login_password: *********
    login_port: 3307
    login_db: mydb
    ca_cert : mydomain-SHA256-Root-CA.crt
    query: |
      LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '/tmp/report.csv'
      INTO TABLE Inventory
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
      ENCLOSED BY '"'
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
      IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

**3. Looping over lines:**

```yaml
- name: Read CSV File
  community.general.read_csv:
    path: /tmp/report.csv
  register: report
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Excute query to db  with positional arguments
  community.mysql.mysql_query:
    login_host: sqltest-lb-fm-in.dbaas.domain.com
    login_user: devops_baseline_db
    login_password: *********
    login_port: 3307
    login_db: mydb
    ca_cert : mydomain-SHA256-Root-CA.crt
    query: |
      INSERT INTO Inventory (Date,Hostname,OS-Version,Package-Name,Pre-installed-Package-Status,Current-Installed-Version,Post-installed-Package-Status,log-loc)
      VALUES ({{ item.Date }},{{ item.Hostname }},{{ item.OS_Version }}, {{ item.Package_Name }},{{ item.Pre_installed_Package_Status }},{{ item.Current_Installed_Version }},{{ item.Post_installed_Package_Status }},{{ item.log_loc }});
  loop: "{{ report }}"
```

I know it's a bit dirty but you can try it. ;)

> Note that I have removed/changed some special characters or you can find some workaround for that